# Python move all files in directory to sub-directory with timestamp in another directory

Tags: python

I have a directory (Unprocessed) in which I have some files.
I need a python way to create a timestamped sub-directory (Pr_DDMMYY_HHMiSS) in another directory (Processed) and move the mentioned files inside that newly created sub-directory (Pr_DDMMYY_HHMiSS). Those to-be-created sub-directories will act as backups for the changes in the files.
Other solution designs are also welcome.

Main directory (unprocessed would host the to-be-processed files and, when processed, those would be moved to processed, in Pr_150321_195708 (Pr_DDMMYY_HHMiSS).

[image]

Unprocessed subdirectory

[image]

Processed subdirectory

[image]

Example of processed folder (after running the process that empties the unprocessed directory and moves the files here.

[image]

Comment: Google: `rsync backup`

Comment: A "directory" is a well-defined object.  A "folder", AFAICT, is a less well defined artifact of a gui.  You seem to be using the two words interchangeably.  Are you making some distinction between the two, or are you just using the two words to mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I was using them interchangeably. Please let me know the correct way to express it so I can rephrase my question.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer looks interesting. Do you have any example handy so I can try to shadow it?

Comment: @JaviTorre I would just consistently use the word "directory".  I'm still on a multi-decade long quest to understand what people mean when they say "folder", and why they use that word, so I ask every now and then when I see someone using both words.

Comment: @WilliamPursell that's the question rephrased. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Add some example on of a sample folder structure and how it should look like after running the script

Comment: As already mentioned, `rsync` is an excellent backup tool.  If you’re looking for change / version management, `git` is a nice solution.  Depends on how in-depth you’re looking to go.

Comment: @lnogueir please find an edit on the original question with screenshots. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @S3DEV not sure if rsync can help me here. I've attached some screenshots on the original questions for more clarity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so what you want to do is: run the script to move (or is it copy?) all files currently in the ```Unprocessed``` directory to a new directory inside ```Processed``` named with the format ```Pr_DDMMYY_HHMiSS```. Please correct me if I am wrong and confirm me whether you want to copy or move the files over.

Comment: That is correct. I'd like to move the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script is on the same folder as `Processed` and `Unprocessed` directories, you could do this:

```py
import os, shutil, datetime

UNPROCESSED_PATH = 'Unprocessed'
PROCESSED_PATH = 'Processed'

try:
    filesToMove = os.listdir(UNPROCESSED_PATH)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"No '{UNPROCESSED_PATH}' directory found")
    exit()

if len(filesToMove) == 0:
    print('No files to process')
    exit()

currTime = datetime.datetime.now()
currTimeStr = currTime.strftime("%d%m%y_%H%M%S")

newDirPath = f'{PROCESSED_PATH}/Pr_{currTimeStr}'
os.mkdir(newDirPath)
print(f'Created {newDirPath} directory')

for file in filesToMove:
    shutil.move(f'{UNPROCESSED_PATH}/{file}', f'{newDirPath}/{file}')
    print(f'Moving {file}')

print(f'Done processing {len(filesToMove)} files')
```

Tested with `Python 3.6.4` on a `Windows Pro`.

Comment: Thanks! I've already adapted it to my script and it's working fine. One question: what does the exit() do in your program? I've replaced it with an else statement but I'd like to understand its behaviour anyway.

Comment: The ```exit()``` there is just to quit the script. You could put a ```return``` instead depending on your context.